# Creators Update Target Version UWP

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, project-settings, creators-update

for UWP project I cant target creators update 15063. why that option is missing?
my windows has been upgraded to creators update but after installing VS.

I have VS 2015, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Is there any way I can update my VS so I can choose creators update as target for my UWP projects?

I need to target creators update because I want to use AsyncEx library by Stephen clearly, the latest version is not compatible with other targets.

I don't want to download a new VS from scratch, because I don't have access to high speed internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you will need Visual Studio 2017 to be able to target Creators Update.

> Note: Windows 10 app development targeting Windows 10 Creators Update
>   requires Visual Studio 2017. This SDK will not be discovered by
>   previous versions of Visual Studio.

[Link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Comment: drag, that will take so long :( , but thanks for the quick answer with reference.

Comment: Yeah... But VS17 installation is an entire new experience and I think you will like it. :)

Comment: As Jessica said, the VS2017 installer is an entirely different experience, and it's actually pretty quick. It's more modular than VS2015. Just don't install Xamarin for 2017 if you use Xamarin in 2015 - it will overwrite any previous version and is not backwards compatible. Other than that, VS2017 is well worth the upgrade.